# Why does Robomongo crash when I connect to my ec2 instance using ssh?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

I try to connect to my mongo database on my ec2 instance. I can do it using the shell with no problem.

On robomongo, I can also connect to the "test" database (empty), all green (ssh ok, ssh tunneling ok, login mongo ok).

However, if I set "local", "admin", or my db name in the Authentication tab, in the database field, robomongo close with no warnings.

Is this a known issue? What can I do?

Comment: Which MongoDB version do you use?

Comment: The latest one. See https://github.com/paralect/robomongo/issues/1152#issuecomment-239127677 . It seems to be a legit bug, but maybe I overlooked something .

Comment: Robomongo doesn't support MongoDB with WiredTiger, which is used by default since 3.2 version. It's only a planned goal. See https://robomongo.org/campaign

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit off, I answered like if you asked what robomongo version I use. Concerning mongo, it is a pre v3 version, so it should be working.